# Titanium SDK update for current user

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

my system has 2 users and a user has installed titanium studio and developed some apps.but he is using old titanium SDK 1.6.

he installed titanium in common, i.e) it available for both the users.

now I want to upgrade titanium sdk only for my user level, that should not affect his Titanium SDK.

is this possible to do in MAC OSX-Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robin, You can select your older SDK as given in the picture.

[image: Titanium SDK]

Look at the circled portions. You can select the SDK either when you creating a new project or after creating the project, select the project configuration by opening the tiApp.xml overview( rounded at the bottom) and select the required SDK.

You can also edit the SDK version in the tiApp.xml by editing

`<sdk-version>2.1.3.GA</sdk-version>`  to  `<sdk-version>required version</sdk-version>`

As Mr.Rene said, there won't be any problem for updating your SDK. Updating your SDK will help to improve your SDK and it fixes the bugs in the SDK

Answer (score 2):

When you update Titanium SDK, the older ones stay too.

You can update this in tiapp.xml, where you can select the SDK to use for the specific App. (not the xml editor, but the other one).

Same thing when you create a new app, you can select the SDK version.

With the current apps, an SDK is linked to it. It will not change when you update.

Conclusion: Don't worry about updating, just do it.